# ruby bitwise operations on IPv4 addresses

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I'm doing some work with IP addresses and I would like to convert "slash notation" (e.g., /28) to dotted quad (e.g., 255.255.255.240)

Internally representing the IP and mask as a large integer is handy for different types of operations and conversions.

So I figured I would drop a 1 on the left, and shift right and drop another 1 there as many times as the slash indicates:

```
mask=0
28.times do
   mask>>=
   mask+=2**31
end
print "%x\n" % mask
```

... but for some reason this doesn't work.

I hear that Ruby automatically converts integers to larger sizes as needed.  I'll be doing a lot of bitwise operations in these routines, but the number of significant digits is very stable.

What's the right way to do bitwise operations on IPv4 addresses in Ruby?

Comment: Take a help from Ruby stdlib - http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-mask

Comment: another link - https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139035#618171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> '%b' % (1 << n)
=> "10000000000000000000000000000"
>> '%b' % ((1 << n) - 1)
=> "1111111111111111111111111111"
>> '%b' % (((1 << n) - 1) << (32-n))
=> "11111111111111111111111111110000"
```

Combining with [`IPAddr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html):

```
require 'ipaddr'
IPAddr.new(((1 << n) - 1) << (32-n), Socket::AF_INET).to_s
# => "255.255.255.240"
```

or as Arup Rakshit commented, use [`IPAddr#mask`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-mask):

```
IPAddr.new('255.255.255.255').mask(28).to_s
"255.255.255.240"
```